# Configuration Error in webconfig

Tags: .net-3.5

I have a small web app for reporting and im encountering problems with it. when i run the application on my local machine it works but when it is on our server it doesn't. My application i using .Net 3.5 framework and the server has the framework installed to it...

here's the error

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'type'.

Source Error: 


Line 2:  <configuration>
Line 3:     <configSections>
Line 4:         <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
Line 5:             <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
Line 6:                 <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>


Source File: d:\inetpub\wwwroot\harrisinterface\web.config    Line: 4 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2407; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2407
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you are using .NET 3.5. The error says that your virtual directory is using .NET 1.1 (`Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2407; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2407`). Check your virtual directory configurations and everything should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is running under .NET 1.1; you should to enable .NET 2.0.

Here is a tutorial: [Where's my .NET 3.5 (on IIS), Dude?](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/289139.aspx)